# Bubble Wrap/Zip Lock - Harry Potter Wands

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, indian-citizens, tsa

I am planning to take Harry Potter Wand collection with me from US to India. I want them to wrap them either in bubble wrap or paper so that they do not get damaged as these will be put in check-in baggage.

Will wrapping the wands in bubble wrap trigger any false-positive for TSA during scanning?

Comment: Looks like an opinion based question.

Comment: @Soumya are you trying to avoid getting them damaged, avoid having your bags opened to examine them, avoid having them stolen, or something else?  It's not clear what you're aiming to prevent.

Comment: @dlanod I am trying more or less everything you mentioned but mainly prevent it from getting damage. Anyways if the TSA wants, they can open the bag for inspection (and I do not think during that time it will get stolen).

Comment: @Karlson True. That's why wanted to know the opinion from the community.

Comment: @Soumya Which specifically considered a bad question.

Comment: @Karlson I have modified the question but it is still on hold. Can you please let me know if I need reword the question.

Comment: @Soumya No.  You will just need to wait now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wands are probably just wood and/or plastic; it will not cause problems with scanners; if they can scan computers and other electronic gadgets, then toys will not be an issue.

Just wrap them in your cloths in your check-in luggage.